# How to plot a complex system related to its imaginary parts

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, complex-numbers

I've defined the complex symbolic system :

```
syms x 
sys(x) = ((10+1.*i.*x))/(20+(5.*i.*x)+((10.*i.*x).^2))+((1.*i.*x).^3); 
ImaginaryPart = imag(sys)
RealPart = real(sys)
```

MATLAB returned the following results:

```
ImaginaryPart(x) =

- real(x^3) + imag((10 + x*1i)/(- 100*x^2 + x*5i + 20))


RealPart(x) =

- real(x^3) + imag((10 + x*1i)/(- 100*x^2 + x*5i + 20))
```

Now how is it possible to `plot(x,sys(x))` or `plot(x,ImaginaryPart(x))` as a complex surface?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For plotting it's required to use a range of values. So, using `x = a + b*i`:

```
[a,b] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10); %// creates two grids
ComplexValue = a+1i*b;        %// get a single, complex valued grid
CompFun = @(x)(- real(x.^3) + imag((10 + x.*1i)./(- 100.*x.^2 + x.*5i + 20))); %// add dots for element wise calculation
result = CompFun(ComplexValue); %// get results
pcolor(a,b,result) %// plot
shading interp %// remove grid borders by interpolation
colorbar %// add colour scale
ylabel 'Imaginary unit'
xlabel 'Real unit'
```

[image]

I did have to add dots (i.e. element wise multiplication) to your equation to make it work.

Additionally with the [`contourf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) as suggested in the [comment by @AndrasDeak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243186/how-to-plot-complex-system-related-to-its-imaginary-parts/35243404?noredirect=1#comment58200907_35243404):

```
figure
contourf(a,b,result,51) %// plots with 51 contour levels
colorbar
```

I used a meshgrid of `-10:0.01:10` here for more resolution:

[image]

If you are reluctant to hand-copy the solution to add the element wise multiplication dots, you can resort to loops:

```
grid = -10:0.1:10;
result(numel(grid),numel(grid))=0; %// initialise output grid
for a = 1:numel(grid)
    for b = 1:numel(grid)
        x = grid(a)+1i*grid(b);
        result(a,b) = ImaginaryPart(x);
    end
end
```

This delivers the same result, but with pros and cons both. It's slower than matrix-multiplication, i.e. than adding dots to your equation, but it does not require manipulating the output by hand.

Comment: Consider using a `contourf` instead/as well, with a lot of levels: zeroes are clearly visible then.

Comment: @LuisMendo here it is in `jet`, specially for you: https://i.imgur.com/QQijOZb.png

Comment: @Adriaan This should be a good illustration of what "perceptually uniform" means and why people don't like `jet`. It's the Comic Sans of color maps!